# Why I can't get bind_result working and assign some of the values to a session?

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a prepared statement, supposed to login a user, everything works just fine, but I'm facing a problem with `bind_result()`. What I mean is that it is not working at all and I can't get the query's result and assign it to the `SESSION`

Here is my code:

```
session_start();
$sesUsername = "";
$sesCid = "";
$sesFirstName = "";
$sesLastName = ""; 
$mysqli = new mysqli($host_l, $username_l, $password_l, $dbName_l);
$loginQuery = "SELECT username, cid, first_name, last_name FROM Users WHERE username=? and password=?";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($loginQuery)){
          $stmt->bind_param('ss',$usernameEsc, $passwordEsc);
          $stmt->execute();

          /* Store the result (to get properties) */
          $stmt->store_result();

          /* Get the number of rows */
          $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

          /* Bind the result to variables */
          $stmt->bind_result($sesUsername, $sesCid, $sesFirstName, $sesLastName);

          if($num_of_rows == 1){
               $_SESSION['username']= $sesUsername; // This is not working
               return true;
           }
           else {               
               http_response_code(401);
            }

          /* free results */
          $stmt->free_result();

          /* close statement */
          $stmt->close();
}
          /* close connection */
          $mysqli->close();
```

The code redirects me to the members area, but in there the session variable `username` is empty.

Why I can't get it working? I know that I'm missing something really small, but as a newbie, I can't spot the problem.

Comment: Where/how are these being defined? `$usernameEsc, $passwordEsc`

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is way before this code, but the query works and logs me in, or throws an error message when the username or the pass are wrong. The problem is not in these variables. :)

Comment: OK, Well add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` if you're not already doing so. See if it catches anything wrong.

Comment: is session been set when data been hardcoded in the top of page immediately after `session_start()`, say for example `$_SESSION['username']= 'testing';` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm so ashamed! `Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement` Can you make quick answer, so I can accept it? :)

Comment: It's ok, I'm just glad it worked out. I no longer give answers anymore, thanks for the offer though. Ask one of the guys with the answers below to add what I said above, in order to close the question.

Comment: Where is the mismatch in the number of variables?

Comment: You have two `?` in the query and two parameters in `bind_param`. You have 4 columns being selected, and 4 variables in `bind_result`.

Comment: @chility If you've solved it yourself, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 4):

You have to do:

```
$stmt->fetch();
```

to get the results into the variables.

Comment: I can't get it working. :( For some reason the session variable can't get assigned, but the query returns the result.

Comment: Make sure you're calling `session_start()` at the very beginning of the script.

Comment: OP does have it. @Barmar it was something else. See comments under OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$stmt->bind_result($sesUsername, $sesCid, $sesFirstName, $sesLastName);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
       $_SESSION['username']= $sesUsername;
   }
```

Comment: The session variable is still empty. :(

Comment: Why do you need a `while` loop for a query that returns a single row?